# Converting RxJava to RxScala

Tags: rx-java, rx-scala

Is there a way to use both *RxJava* and *RxScala* in one project?

```
import rx.lang.scala.{Observable => ScalaObservable}
import rx.{Observable => JavaObservable}
```

We have a module written in Java that is using the `JavaObservable` (*RxJava*). And then we have a Scala module that is supposed to use the Java module but is written in Scala.

Are there convenient methods to transform these into the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using the conversion functions such as `toJavaObservable`, `toScalaObservable`, etc in [rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions$).

You can either write the conversion explicitly (eg `toJavaObservable(myScalaObservable)`, or if you enable implicit conversions and `import rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions._`, they will be inserted automatically by the compiler whenever a Java Observable is expected, but a Scala Observable is found, and vice versa.