# Convert RxJava Observable to RxScala Observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-scala, rx-javafx

I am writing a small JavaFx application in Scala and I like to use RxScala and RxJavaFx for this. With the following code I get a **RxJava** `Observable`:

```
JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty())
```

Obviously, as I write in Scala, I would like to have a **RxScala** `Observable` instead. Now I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264748/converting-rxjava-to-rxscala), saying that I either have to import the implicit conversion class `JavaConversions._` or call `toScalaObservable` directly. However, the first option doesn't do it for me and the second option looks kind of ugly:

**Option 1:**

```
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions._
JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty())
  .map(s => /* do something */)
```

This doesn't work, as RxJava offers a `map` operator as well, although the type of the argument is technically speaking different.

**Option 2:**

```
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions._
toScalaObservable(JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty()))
  .map(s => /* do something */)
```

This works, but be honest people, this looks just really horrible!

**Question 1:** Am I missing something or are these really the only two options?

I mean, to convert from Java's standard collections to Scala's collections (and vise versa) you got two option: `JavaConverters` and `JavaConversions`. The former introduces a keyword `asJava`/`asScala`, whereas the latter is kind of equivalent to `rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions` and does the conversion for you implicitly (if you're lucky!). Googling on the preferences of these two, it is clear that most people prefer the more explicit implicit conversion from `JavaConverters` with the `asScala` keyword.

**Question 2:** Is there a similar construction like `JavaConverters` with RxScala? This would make the code above so much more cleaner, I would say:

```
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConverters._ // this class doesn't exist!
JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty())
  .asScala
  .map(s => /* do something */)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was the starting point of [this pull request](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/pull/207) on the RxScala project.

The syntax proposed in the original question can be used by importing `rx.lang.scala.JavaConverters`.

```
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConverters._
JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty())
  .asScala
  .map(s => /* do something */)
```

Likewise a Scala `Observable` can be transformed into a Java `Observable` using `asJava`.

See also the [examples](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/0.x/examples/src/test/scala/examples/JavaConvertersDemo.scala) of intended use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write your example as follows:

```scala
import rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions._
val texts: Observable[String] = JavaFxObservable.fromObservableValue(textfield.textProperty())
texts.map(s => /* do something */)
```

where `Observable[String]` is the Scala Observable.
Giving an explicit type for the val `texts` ensures that the implicit conversion kicks in.

**Why no `asScala`?**

This would require another implicit wrapper class (let's call in `PreScalaObservable`), with only one method called `toScala`, so that when you'd write `myJavaObservable.toScala`, the compiler would turn it into something like `toPreScalaObservable(myJavaObservable).toScala`.

Having two wrapper classes would be a bit confusing. Or if you're very smart, you could actually put the `asScala` method into the Scala Observable and implement it just as returning `this`, and since the Java Observable has no method called `asScala`, `myJavaObservable.toScala` would work. But again, this might be quite complex to grasp for beginners...

But if you have a better idea, or know how to present this simply, I encourage you to open an issue in the [RxScala issues](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/issues); the project is still in 0.x and nothing is set in stone... ;-)

Comment: To be honest, I really like the chaining of all the operators. That's one of the defining powers of the Rx API (as it is with the Scala Collections API). Having to introduce extra `val`s including explicit typing isn't something I particularly like to do and see in Scala. It's a trick that works though, that's for certain! I will look into this some more and definitely consider moving this discussion the the RxScala issues. I assume I can do a pull request myself as well over there. Let's keep in tough on this!

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need to convert form RXJava to RXScala?, RXScala has all the same features that RXJava has. 
For example

ZIP:

```
  @Test def zip(): Unit = {
    addHeader("Observable zip")
    Observable.just("hello")
      .zip(Observable.just(" scala"))
      .zip(Observable.just(" world!"))
      .map(s => s._1._1.concat(s._1._2).concat(s._2).toUpperCase)
      .subscribe(s => println(s));
  }
```

MERGE:

```
  @Test def merge(): Unit = {
    addHeader("Observable merge")
    Observable.just("hello")
      .merge(Observable.just(" scala"))
      .merge(Observable.just(" world!"))
      .reduce((s, s1) => s.concat(s1))
      .map(s => s.toUpperCase).subscribe(s => println(s))
  }
```

FLATMAP:

```
  @Test def flatMap(): Unit = {
    addHeader("Flat Map")
    val text = "number mutated in flatMap::"
    val list = getList
    Observable.from(list)
      .flatMap(n => Observable.just(n) //--> New pipeline
        .map(n => text.concat(String.valueOf(n))))
      .map(s => s.toUpperCase())
      .subscribe(s => println(s))
  }
```

I would start from scratch to be honest with you.
If you want to take a look of more operator examples https://github.com/politrons/reactiveScala

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean! Are you arguing "*Why is there a RxScala if it has all the same features as RxJava?*"? My reason for asking how to convert between RxJava and RxScala is because Java's lambda expressions don't match with Scala's lambdas as of 2.11 and having a consistency in your code (use RxScala everywhere in your app) is also a nice thing. Maybe you could explain a bit more of what you wanted to say with "Why converting" and "starting from scratch".

Comment: maybe I did not understand you, are you using JavaConverters because there´s no way to do with RXScala the same thing than JavaFxObservable?. I was suggesting that with RXScala you can do exactly the same than with RxJava so there´s no need to port any code from Java

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Indeed in this case I came to this issue via RxJavaFx, which wraps JavaFx UI events in an `Observable` (which in itself is pretty useful!), but I was thinking of a general API that provides me with a RxJava `Observable`, which needs to be converted into a RxScala `Observable`. I fully acknowledge the fact that RxScala in itself is a wrapper for Scala around the RxJava library, but it has some stuff that works better with RxScala if you're writing in Scala. For example, the difference in lambda's that I mentioned before...